# How can I get the data from a span in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my code, I want to take the location's name and link, the variable "lugares" finds multiple item-containers, but I only want the first one [0]; then goes the for loop, but I can't find the span classes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

b=[]
i="https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx"
url = "https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx/s-renta-inmuebles/estado-de-mexico/v1c1098l1014p1"

encabezado = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36",'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'}

page =requests.get(url,headers=encabezado)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

lugares = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"items-container"})

lugares=lugares[0]
print(len(lugares))

for lugar in lugares:
    
    locationlink = i + str(lugar.find("span",{"class":"item"}).find("a")["href"])

    location= lugar.find("span",{"class":"item"}).text
    a=[location,locationlink]
    
    b.append(a)
```

Comment: Are you after the entries in the top bar e.g. Chicoloapan?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get all `spans` in the first Lugares `lugares[0]`.

Then you need to iterate for each span to get the link and text for each location.

**The Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

b=[]
i="https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx"
url = "https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx/s-renta-inmuebles/estado-de-mexico/v1c1098l1014p1"

encabezado = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36",'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'}

page =requests.get(url,headers=encabezado)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

lugares = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"items-container"})

#lugares=lugares[0]
print(len(lugares))

# get all spans
spans = lugares[0].find_all("span",{"class":"item"})

# itreate throw each span
for span in spans: 
    # get location text
    location = span.find("a").text

    # locationlink builder
    site = "www.vivanuncios.com.mx"
    link = span.find("a")["href"]
    locationlink = f"{site}{link}"   

    a = [location,locationlink]
    b.append(a)

print (b[0])
```

**Output:**

```
['Huixquilucan', 'www.vivanuncios.com.mx/s-renta-inmuebles/huixquilucan/v1c1098l10689p1']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to get the goal, best one depence on what you expect and wanna do with this information in follow up process.

#### First Option

If you are just looking for the infos of first location you can do the following:

```
lugar = soup.select_one('div.items-container a')   
b = [lugar.text, f'{i}{lugar["href"]}']
```

or

```
lugar = soup.select('div.items-container a')[0]
b = [lugar.text, f'{i}{lugar["href"]}']
```

Both select the first `<a>` in the `<div>` with class `items-container`.

#### Output

```
['Huixquilucan','https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx/s-renta-inmuebles/huixquilucan/v1c1098l10689p1']
```

#### Alternativ

If you are interested to get all at once, you should use a list of `dicts`, so later on you just have to iterate it and get all information in place:

```
[{'name':x.text, 'link':f'{i}{x["href"]}'} for x in soup.select('div.items-container a')]
```

#### Output

```
[{'name': 'Huixquilucan',
  'link': 'https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx/s-renta-inmuebles/huixquilucan/v1c1098l10689p1'},
 {'name': 'Naucalpan',
  'link': 'https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx/s-renta-inmuebles/naucalpan/v1c1098l10710p1'},
 {'name': 'Atizapán',
  'link': 'https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx/s-renta-inmuebles/atizapan/v1c1098l10662p1'},
 {'name': 'Metepec',
  'link': 'https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx/s-renta-inmuebles/metepec-edomex/v1c1098l10707p1'},...]
```

#### Example (showing results of both)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

i="https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx"
url = "https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx/s-renta-inmuebles/estado-de-mexico/v1c1098l1014p1"

encabezado = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36",'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'}

page =requests.get(url,headers=encabezado)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

lugar = soup.select_one('div.items-container a')
b = [lugar.text, f'{i}{lugar["href"]}']
print(f'First lugar:\n {b} \n')

## or alternative option

allLugaros = [{'name':x.text, 'link':f'{i}{x["href"]}'} for x in soup.select('div.items-container a')]

print(f'First lugar from lugaros (list of dict):\n {allLugaros[0]} \n')
print(f'All lugaros as list of dict:\n {allLugaros} \n')
```